# How to make a parent object in CSS menu stay in hover state when children are hovered over

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to make a menu work so that the menu remains in hover state when it's submenu/child menu is selected:

see example here: http://cssdesk.com/5vJP6

If anyone could explain what needs to be added to the CSS to make this work that would be great. I don't want to use any external javascript to make this happen!

I've had a look at a couple of similar questions here, but none of their answers worked for me

thanks

Comment: I'd put the class (top_parent) on the list item instead of the link

Comment: check http://www.cssplay.co.uk/

Comment: @kalpaitch - could you expand on that please? (or paste it somewhere?)

Comment: this isn't my website. it has many drop down menus that works across all the browsers, you can see which ever fits your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this:

```
#menuh ul li:hover a  {color: black !important; border-bottom: 1px dashed #C1D9F0 !important;   }
#menuh ul li:hover li a {color: #505050 !important;}
#menuh ul li:hover li a:hover   {color:  #297BB6 !important;  }
```

Which resolved my problem :-)

Comment: You could also use `#menuh > ul > li:hover a`, however that is not supported by IE6.

Answer (score 2):

Define the `:hover` on the `li` element instead of the link, for example:

```
#menuh li:hover A
{
}
```

(Dito for all `a:hover`s)

However this won't work in IE6. You'll need to have to JavaScript solution there.

Comment: Thanks this has helped - however it seems to have taken over the hover styles of each of the list items (they used to have blue backgrounds before adding rows 113-120) - how would I go about making them different again?

Answer (score 1):

This was super helpful! Here's what I ended up using to make sure the background and font color of my main nav didn't override the sub nav

```
#nav ul li:hover a  {background-color: #353535; color: #A98C0C;}
#nav ul li:hover li a {background:none; color: #aaa; }
#nav ul li:hover li a:hover   {background:none; color: #fff;   }
```